# Trouble with delimiters in Eclipse 3.8.1

Tags: eclipse

i'm having problems setting the delimiter to UNIX i tried

[Eclipse and Windows newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886185/eclipse-and-windows-newlines)

[Eclipse Editor: How to change file format from Dos to Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374728/eclipse-editor-how-to-change-file-format-from-dos-to-unix)

I follow the instructions but when i do i new check out from the svn repository the delimiters files are Windows.

i don't know what else to do

Comment: Does SVN itself have a way of forcing line delimiters on text files?

Answer (score 0):

> but when i do i new check out from the svn repository the delimiters files are Windows.

It must be because someone who made the last commit, was working on a windows machine and he/she accidentally committed the .project configuration files for eclipse on svn as well. So now when you check out the project, your configuration file for the project is getting overwritten by the new one.

Configuration files should never be pushed to repositories.

Comment: Had they pushed the *right* values, would you be saying otherwise?

Comment: Maybe, but I have seen this happen a lot of times in my experiences thats why its my first guess

Comment: it's possible but where i work is most common to use Linux than windows , i test it downloading an svn file where the owner is working with linux and it does the same thing (sorry if my English is not right)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587806/is-there-anyway-to-get-tortoisesvn-to-leave-eol-line-endings-as-is